# Can I use another variable as a key in Golang templates?

Tags: go

I have a data structure that is sometihng like:

```
map[string]SomeStructure
```

I have another struct that encapsulates the above plus additional variables and other structs and that's what gets sent to the template:

```
type page struct {
    Status   map[string]SomeStructure
    Database  []string
}
```

In my template file I want to be able to do something like

```
{{ range index .Database}} 
    {{ .Status "KEY".MemberVariableOfSomeStructure }}
{{ end }}
```

Except I want the "KEY" to be dynamic based on the iterating .Database value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [index](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions) function to access a map.

```
{{ range .Database }} 
    {{ index $.Status . }}
{{ end }}
```

See [play](https://play.golang.org/p/cJebtPvRMX).